# Adding a line break to D3 graph y-axis labels

Tags: javascript, text, svg, d3.js

I am trying to add a line break to the y-axis labels on my D3 graph, which displays bandwidth moved. At the moment it displays inline `5 GB`, I would like it to display like so,

```
5
GB
```

So, since there is no easy way of adding a line break to a svg text element, I opted for selecting all of the text elements after they have been rendered, I split them at the space and positioned them in `<tspan>` elements inside of the text element, with the `GB` positioned slightly lower than the value, which seemed to work, except for the labels not displaying at all, even though they did exist on the page.

Here is a snippet of the code,

```
    function init(svg,data,width,height,margin){

      var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,data[0].length-1])
        .range([margin.left, width-margin.right]),

      y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,d3.max(data[0])])
        .range([height-margin.bottom, margin.top]),

      /* Define stock x and y axis */
      xAxis = d3.svg
                .axis()
                .ticks(data[0].length)
                .tickFormat(function(d) { return d+1; })
                .scale(x)
                .orient('bottom'),

      yAxis = d3.svg
                .axis()
                .scale(y)
                .tickFormat(function(d) { return bytesToSize(d,0); })
                .orient('right'),

      /* line path generator */
      line = d3.svg.line().interpolate('monotone')
        .x(function(d,i) { return x(i); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d); }),

      /* area path generator */
      area = d3.svg.area().interpolate('monotone')
        .x(line.x())
        .y1(line.y())
        .y0(y(0)),

      /* add the groups */
      groups = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g");

      /* add the circles */
      svg.select("g")
        .selectAll("circle")
      .data(data[0])
      .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class","dot")
        .attr("cx", line.x())
        .attr("cy", line.y())
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .style("fill","#008cc2")
        .style("stroke","#008cc2")
        .style("stroke-width","1.5px");

        /* add the axes */
        svg.append('g')
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+(height - 20)+")")
                .call(xAxis)
                .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("dx", "-.3em")
                .attr("dy", "-.3em")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "rotate(-90)"
                });

        svg.append('g')
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis);

      /* add the areas */
      area = groups.append("path")
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d",area)
        .style("opacity",0.3)
        .style("fill", function(d,i) {
            return (i == 0 ? "#008cc2" : "#7500c6" );
        });

      /* add the lines */
      groups.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line)
        .style("fill","none")
        .style("stroke-width", "1.5px")
        .style("stroke", function(d,i) {
            return (i == 0 ? "#008cc2" : "#7500c6" );
        });

    var insertLinebreaks = function (d) {
        var el = $(d3.select(this).node());
        var sections = bytesToSize(d,0);

        console.log(sections[0]);
        console.log(sections[1]);

        el.text('');
        el.append('<tspan>'+sections[0]+'</tspan>');
        el.append('<tspan x="0" dy="3">'+sections[1]+'</tspan>');

    };

    svg.selectAll('g.y.axis g text').each(insertLinebreaks);

    }

function bytesToSize(bytes, precision)
{
    var kilobyte    = 1024;
    var megabyte    = kilobyte * 1024;
    var gigabyte    = megabyte * 1024;
    var terabyte    = gigabyte * 1024;

    if ((bytes >= 0) && (bytes < kilobyte)) {
        return [bytes,'B'];

    }
    else if ((bytes >= kilobyte) && (bytes < megabyte))
    {
        return [(bytes / kilobyte).toFixed(precision),'KB'];

    }
    else if ((bytes >= megabyte) && (bytes < gigabyte))
    {
        return [(bytes / megabyte).toFixed(precision),'MB'];

    }
    else if ((bytes >= gigabyte) && (bytes < terabyte))
    {
        return [(bytes / gigabyte).toFixed(precision),'GB'];

    }
    else if (bytes >= terabyte)
    {
        return [(bytes / terabyte).toFixed(precision),'TB'];

    }
    else
    {
        return [bytes,'B'];
    }
}
```

Basically I would like to add a line break to a svg text element. I've tried a few methods, but to no avail.

Comment: Did you check that the relevant `tspan` elements are created as you would expect?

Comment: I did, yes. The HTML is there, but nothing is displaying.

Comment: The issue might be that the new elements are added in the HTML and not the SVG namespace. Have you tried appending the `tspan` elements using D3 or creating them explicitly with the correct namespace?

Comment: That did the trick, adding the namespace fixed it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Ok, I'll add that as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding the `tspan` elements as text without a namespace. This way they get interpreted as HTML. If you add them using D3 or explicitly create the elements with a namespace, it should work, i.e.

```
el.text('');
d3.select(el).append("tspan").text(sections[0]);
...
```